mongoDB - complex geometric operations (e.g. $geointersect) for plane 2d indices
Is there a possibility to use the powerful geometric query options in mongoDB (e.g. defining geometries like points, lines, paths and polygons and querying for object intersection with $geoIntersects) also on plane 2d indices (x,y cartesian coordinates) instead of 2dsphere indices with longitude and latitude?
By default it seems that mongoDB supports these powerful operations only on GeoJSON objects with a 2dsphere index.

It is possible with a 2d index. But for 2d index, you have to use legacy coordinate pairs

But 2d index does support neither $geoIntersects nor geometries like PolyLines as far as I read from the docs.

And when you change your example to coordinates greater than 180 you will also get an error query failed: (BadValue) longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 300 lat: 600. So it queries the $geoIntersect still in the lat/long range.
